Equivalence between equality as a left adjoint and as a right adjoint
Given a hyperdoctrine $P : C^{op} → HA$ it is common to define equality as a left adjoint to contraction
$$ \dfrac{weak(φ) ∧ =_σ ⊢ ψ : P\ (σ × σ)}{φ ⊢ contr(ψ) : P\ σ} $$
Here $$weak := P\ π : P\ \Gamma → P\ (\Gamma × σ)$$ for $π : \Gamma × σ → \Gamma$: given a formula of variables in $\Gamma$, it gives the same formula with an unused variable of sort $σ$ ---in this case---;
$$contr := P\ (id×δ) : P\ (\Gamma × σ × σ) → P\ (\Gamma × σ) $$
for $δ : σ → σ × σ$: given a formula that uses two variables of the same sort $φ(x,y)$, it gives the same formula but with only one variable $φ(x,x)$.
And $=_σ$ should be understood as the formula $x=y$ for a pair of variables $x$ and $y$ of sort $σ$.
For the definition of $=_σ$ above we used $\Gamma = 1$.

Of course, equality can be defined also as a right adjoint to contraction:
$$ \dfrac{contr(φ) ⊢ ψ : P\ σ}{φ ⊢ =_σ → weak(ψ) : P\ (σ × σ)} $$
and here lies the question:
Can you derive one in terms of the other?
I've been trying but to no avail.
Of course many details should be given about the exact definitions that are being used to see how it's proved. But I just haven't been able to prove this and it's more tricky and devious than initially meets the eye. If more precision of the definitions is needed, it may be given.

Writing everything in the internal logic of a hyperdoctrine is fine for an answer.
Thanks in advance!

I feel like some of your expressions don't make a lot of sense, but maybe I'm not familiar enough with hyperdoctrines. By "adjoint" do you mean the usual notion from category theory? If so, could you spell out exactly which functors are left/right adjoint to each other? Also $P\Gamma \times\sigma \times \sigma \to \Gamma \times \sigma$ doesn't look well-typed.

Also $P\pi$ would have type $P\Gamma \to P(\Gamma \times \sigma)$.

@NaïmFavier thank you! edited. Indeed now it's better.

I don't think your formulas are defining $=_\sigma$ as a left (or right) adjoint to anything, in the usual sense of the word. What is true is that the equality predicate $=_\sigma$ can be defined as $\exists_\delta(\top)$, where $\exists_\delta : P\sigma \to P(\sigma \times \sigma)$ is left adjoint to $P\delta : P(\sigma \times \sigma) \to P\sigma$. You can also define inequality $\neq_\sigma$ as $\forall_\delta(\bot)$, but I'm not sure this is what you're after.

Interesting, I never thought about it this way. It is true though that people present equality as a left adjoint to contraction in the literature, and this gives almost immediately the rules of introduction and elimination of equality.

Can you give a source for that definition?

With your definition you get the following rule: $ \dfrac{=_\sigma \vdash \psi}{\vdash weak(\psi)} $

I think you mean $\mathrm{contr}$ instead of $\mathrm{weak}$.

The existential is left adjoint to weakening. (This is saying that the variable doesn't appear free in $\psi$.)

I just saw that the nlab defines it as you say, and has an interesting definition using beck chevalley that I didn't know about. The presentation I knew about was Pitts', e.g: tripos theory in retrospect, it is defined in the third page.

Then I am confused because Pitts's definition is exactly the same as mine and the nlab's (evaluate the left adjoint to contraction at $\top$) and the inference rules you give in  your question don't appear in that paper AFAICT.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
